# Will reportviewer of Visual Basic can do a report that came in MS ACCESS database file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Is there any possibility to make a report using MS ACCESS database files? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 however no reportviewer, just saw a source to download and have a toolbox for it however seems not working to make a new report since it lacks Report Wizard and Create a Report thus available only in paid.

Any alternatives to make simple but useful way of making a report?

Comment: Can anyone provide me a suggestion if how to make a report in VB express version?